# Reduce image size in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, image-resizing

I used ImageOptimizer package for reducing image size.

source: http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation

in controller

```
         use Image;

         if (Input::hasFile('title_image')) {
            /*$this->validate($request,[
                'photo' =>'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048'
            ]);*/

            $Product = Input::file('title_image');
            $Product->move(public_path() . '/../../products', md5($Product->getClientOriginalName()) . ".png");

            $product->title_img = "products/" . md5($Product->getClientOriginalName()) . ".png";

        }
```

Now I want to convert image in this function when I upload. if I add this method `$img = Image::make('foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);` it says storage not found error. 
Now what can I do. please give me some suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please use "resize function" before move into desire folder.

```
 use Image;

         if (Input::hasFile('title_image')) {
            /*$this->validate($request,[
                'photo' =>'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048'
            ]);*/

         $Product = Input::file('title_image');
         $filename = time() . '.' . $Product->getClientOriginalExtension();

         Image::make($Product)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename) )->move(public_path() . '/../../products', md5($Product->getClientOriginalName()) . ".png");

         $product->title_img = "products/" . md5($Product->getClientOriginalName()) . ".png";

        }
```

Comment: same problem says.

Comment: yeah, I check this one. but it also says the same errror source not readable. do I have to write any line of code inside route/web.php??

Answer (score 0):

if you want reduce or resize the image you can use the laravel image compression package before upload the image.this is link below how you can do that.
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-compress-image-before-upload-exampleexample.html

image compression is need more because when browser access the url and that page having the more that 10 image then it first download the all image and send request to server to for each due to which its taking more time to load the page.so,get ride from this problem use image compression package.

Comment: This procedure already added in my project. Can you please tell me how to solve this error `image source not readable` ?